# Get Mars DEM Data

Tags: qgis, dem, geotiff-tiff, mars

I'm very very new to QGIS, I'm creating a small GIS project for the planet Mars. It's going along nicely so far, it's easy to find basemaps and the like from open data sources like [PIGWAD](https://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/pigwad/down/mars_dl.htm) and [MOLA](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Mars/GlobalSurveyor/MOLA/Mars_MGS_MOLA_DEM_mosaic_global_463m/cub). But, I'm trying to map mars' elevation, but the only data I can find are jpg or tiff files (see MOLA link). The goal is to create a basic hillshade with GDAL or something similar, but all the tutorials I can find use GeoTiff datasets from SRTM so...the question is how do I get the DEM datasets for mars or is there a way to use the jpg/tiff files for analysing elevation/terrain data?

Comment: If this is likely to be open data you could try the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Many DEMs are rasters, so what's the problem? GeoTIFF is just a particular form of a TIFF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is understanding what a DEM really is. A dem is a [digital elevation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model), mostly a raster that displays the elevation per pixel. A [GeoTIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) is a georeferenced raster image. A DEM can be displayed as a GeoTIFF file. You can work with geotiffs using [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html).